Psycopg hangs on connection
Running the latest (3.2.1) version of th psycopg faced a problem that it hangs on getting connection from the pool to the postgres db. I saw that timeout there is 0.1 so it must raise an error but instead it just got stuck at that point. Are there any way to force it to raise an error if failed to connect?
(Python) File "/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 674, in _init_
self.__connect()
(C) File "/python3.9/Include/internal/pycore_ceval.h", line 40, in function_code_fastcall (/libpython3.9.so.1.0)
(Python) File "/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 896, in __connect
self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
(Python) File "/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 643, in connect
return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
(Python) File "/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 621, in connect
return self.loaded_dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
(Python) File "/psycopg/connection.py", line 103, in connect
rv = waiting.wait_conn(gen, interval=_WAIT_INTERVAL)
(Python) File "/psycopg/waiting.py", line 98, in wait_conn
fileno, s = gen.send(ready)
(C) File "/python3.9/Include/internal/pycore_ceval.h", line 40, in gen_send_ex (/libpython3.9.so.1.0)
(Python) File "/psycopg/_connection_base.py", line 430, in _connect_gen
pgconn = yield from generators.connect(conninfo, timeout=timeout)
(C) File "???", line 0, in PQconnectPoll (/psycopg_binary.libs/libpq-0c1bcb9b.so.5.16)
(C) File "???", line 0, in gss_acquire_cred (/psycopg_binary.libs/libgssapi_krb5-497db0c6.so.2.2)
(C) File "???", line 0, in gss_acquire_cred_from (/psycopg_binary.libs/libgssapi_krb5-497db0c6.so.2.2)
(C) File "???", line 0, in gss_indicate_mechs_by_attrs (/psycopg_binary.libs/libgssapi_krb5-497db0c6.so.2.2)
(C) File "???", line 0, in gss_indicate_mechs (/psycopg_binary.libs/libgssapi_krb5-497db0c6.so.2.2)
(C) File "???", line 0, in updateMechList (/psycopg_binary.libs/libgssapi_krb5-497db0c6.so.2.2)
(C) File "???", line 0, in krb5int_open_plugin (/psycopg_binary.libs/libkrb5support-d0bcff84.so.0.1)
(C) File "/usr/src/debug/glibc-2.28-225.el8.x86_64/dlfcn/dlopen.c", line 87, in dlopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (/usr/lib64/libdl-2.28.so)
(C) File "/usr/src/debug/glibc-2.28-225.el8.x86_64/dlfcn/dlerror.c", line 142, in _dlerror_run (/usr/lib64/libdl-2.28.so)
(C) File "/usr/src/debug/glibc-2.28-225.el8_8.11.x86_64/elf/dl-error-skeleton.c", line 227, in _dl_catch_error (/usr/lib64/libc-2.28.so)
(C) File "/usr/src/debug/glibc-2.28-225.el8_8.11.x86_64/elf/dl-error-skeleton.c", line 208, in _dl_catch_exception (/usr/lib64/libc-2.28.so)
(C) File "/usr/src/debug/glibc-2.28-225.el8.x86_64/dlfcn/dlopen.c", line 66, in dlopen_doit (/usr/lib64/libdl-2.28.so)
(C) File "/usr/src/debug/glibc-2.28-225.el8_8.11.x86_64/elf/dl-open.c", line 927, in _dl_open (/usr/lib64/ld-2.28.so)
(C) File "/usr/src/debug/glibc-2.28-225.el8_8.11.x86_64/elf/dl-close.c", line 138, in _dl_close_worker (/usr/lib64/ld-2.28.so)
(C) File "/usr/src/debug/glibc-2.28-225.el8_8.11.x86_64/elf/dl-close.c", line 508, in _dl_close_worker (inlined) (/usr/lib64/ld-2.28.so)
(C) File "/usr/src/debug/glibc-2.28-225.el8.x86_64/nptl/allocatestack.c", line 1243, in __wait_lookup_done (/usr/lib64/libpthread-2.28.so)
(C) File "../sysdeps/nptl/futex-internal.h", line 135, in futex_wait_simple (inlined) (/usr/lib64/libpthread-2.28.so)
(C) File "../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/futex-internal.h", line 61, in futex_wait (inlined) (/usr/lib64/libpthread-2.28.so)


Could you share the code used?

Try psycopg_pool 3.2.2. This seems to be covered by this issue #784 and should be fixed in 3.2.2 version of psycopg_pool.

@AdrianKlaver sory for the silly question but how can switch to psycopg_pool? I use sqlalchemy for db access, so should I change connection string to force new version of the pool or just install it and nothing else?

The first thing you should do is go to the Python env where your are running this and see what pip freeze | grep psycopg-pool returns. If it is not psycopg-pool==3.2.2 then do pip install --upgrade psycopg-pool. If does return 3.2.2 then this is a different problem.
